# Master Theorem applicable here?

Tags: computability, recurrence-relation, recursion, discrete-mathematics, master-theorem

Let
$T(n):=\begin{cases} \frac{2+\log n}{1+\text{log}n}t(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor) + \log ((n!)^{\log n}) & \text{if }n>1 \\
1 & \text{if }n=1
\end{cases}$

I need to prove that $t(n) \in O(n²)$, thus $t(n) \leq c\cdot n²$

I asked the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689372/prove-big-o-for-a-recursive-function/3689390) and I got really great help last time, the thing is after I was shown last time that $f(n)=\log(n)\cdot\log(n!)$ is $\Theta(2\cdot\log(n)\cdot n) = \Theta(\log(n)\cdot n)$ I thought I could then use the master theorem

However since $a=\frac{2+\log n}{1+\log n}$ is NOT a constant I can not use the master theorem
but I thought that I could use an upper bound for $a$, since $\frac{2+\log n}{1+\log n} < 2 \quad\forall n$ and then use the master theorem for $a=2$, $b=2$. But am I allowed to use the master theorem after finding an upper bound for the non-constant $a$?

What would other ways be to show that $T(n) = O(n^2)$ ?

Comment: Actually, $f(n) = \Theta(n\log^2 n)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: But isn't $\Theta(n \cdot log²n)$=$\Theta(n \cdot (logn)²)$ then with the law of logarithm $\Theta(n \cdot (logn)²)$  = $\Theta(n \cdot 2 \cdot (logn))$=$\Theta(n \cdot (logn))$?

Comment: No. It's not true that $(\log n)^2 = \Theta(\log n)$.

Comment: You might be confused with $\log(n^2)$, which is $\Theta(\log n)$. However, $\log(n^2) \neq (\log n)^2$. For example, if logarithm is base 2 and $n = 2^m$, then $\log(n^2) = 2m$ while $\log^2 n = m^2$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Oh you are completely right! Thanks. But then it would be the second case here https://www.csd.uwo.ca/~mmorenom/CS433-CS9624/Resources/master.pdf. with (a,b = 2 and k=2) and $T(n)=\Theta(n*(log(n)^3)$? How could I then show that $T(n)=\Theta(n²)$?

Comment: You cannot show it since it's false, per Steven's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define $T'(n) = 2 T'(\frac{n}{2}) + \Theta(n \log n)$, notice that $T(n) \le T'(n)$, and use the master theorem on $T'$ to obtain an upper bound of $O(n \log^2 n)$ to $T$.

Since for $n \ge 2$, $\frac{2+\log n}{1+\log n} \le \frac{3}{2}$ you can get a better upper bound by comparing $T$ to
$$T'' = \begin{cases}\frac{3}{2}T''(\frac{n}{2}) + \Theta(n \log n) & \text{if $n\ge2$} \\ \Theta(1) & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ Applying the master theorem on $T''$ yields and upper bound of $O(n \log n)$ for $T$.

Comment: Thank you so much, for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are allowed to use the master's theorem on upper bounds.

Formally, just define S(n) as the function which has the upper bounds (which recursive calls to **itself**) and use the master's theorem on S(n). you know that S(n) is a bound for T(n) (you can prove this in induction if you really want to) and thus if you managed to show that S(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>) then also T(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Personally, i never explained why its possible to use the master's theorem on upper bounds too, and i have never seen anyone try to actually explain it before (since as you have seen from the explanation, the reason is pretty straightforward)

I Hope i managed to help :P

Comment: The master theorem doesn't apply directly. You need to couple the recurrence with another one which does have constant coefficients, as in Steven's answer.

Comment: thank you for the explanation.